# what is the best c++ wrapper to webkit ? for staticlly linking (not QWebkit)

Tags: c++, static, webkit

i need to statically embed web browser in c++ , webkit is good idea , is there any easy c++
wrapper around this kit , i know the Qt version but i can only dynamically link it and its no good for me.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot build it statically ?
http://blog.chaz6.com/2008/09/how-to-build-qt-webkit-trunk-as-static.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, I believe that you can build the Cairo-based Windows port of webkit statically.

[WebKit.org link](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingCairoOnWindows)